# Android SMS Permissions issue

Tags: android, android-permissions

[image]I got mail from google team like this

> We reviewed your request and found that your app, IamKaHO,
>   com.kahocollege.prod, does not qualify for use of the requested
>   permissions for the following reasons: 
>       Your app is not requesting SMS/Call Log permissions group. Please check your manifest, confirm permissions your app requests, and
>   resubmit the declaration form. If your app does not request SMS/Call
>   Log permissions, you do not need to resubmit the declaration form.

But I have declared permission in manifest. I don't know what to do next. Please guide me regarding this

Comment: Because with newer android versions, you need to ask permission to allow access to sms and call log. Have you performed these checks in your code?

Comment: Don't see your app require sms permissions on your play store page

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>`
you have to remove SMS and Call Log permission from your manifest and also remove that run time permission from code and update app as soon as on play store
otherwise google play store suspend your account.

Comment: @SrikarReddy i have declared in manifest and asked permission  through prompt

Comment: Have you pushed the changes to the playstore?

Comment: I see you app needs Phone permissions, dont' see call logs permissions either. The form is used if you app needs SMS/Call logs permissions.

Comment: ya i published in playstore

Comment: Go to *play store (on your mobile), click the description **read more** and scroll to the bottom and click **see more** next to **App permissions**.  Now take a screenshot and add to the question.

Comment: @SrikarReddy screenshot added.. But SMS permission is not showing .

Comment: Exactly, I've extracted the apk on the play store and checked your manifest. I can't find the SMS permission in the manifest either.

Comment: Check if it is the updated version. Update a new version oncegain since you already added the permission.

Comment: @SrikarReddy ok. i will upload again.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187304/discussion-between-karthik-thunga-and-srikar-reddy).